# Logarithmic Slider Control in Mathematica

Tags: user-interface, widget, wolfram-mathematica

I'm making a small interface for calculating voltage dividers in Mathematica. I have two sliders (z1 & z2) that represent the resistor values and a couple of sliders to represent Vin as a sinusoid.

The issue is that the range of available resistor values (in the real world) is roughly logarithmic on `{r, 100, 1,000,000}`. If I set my slider range to `r`, however, it's impractical to select common low resistor values in approx. `{100, 10,000}`.

Is it possible to create a slider that sweeps through a logarithmic range?
`Manipulate[
 Grid[{{Plot[(VinRCos[t] + VinC), {t, -3, 9}, 
     PlotRange -> {-1, VMax}, AxesLabel -> {t, Vin}]}, {Plot[
     z2/(z1 + z2)(VinR*Cos[t] + VinC), {t, -3, 9}, 
     PlotRange -> {-1, VMax}, AxesLabel -> {t, Vout}]}}, 
  ItemSize -> 20],
 {{z1, 10000}, 10, 1000000, 10}, {z1}, {{z2, 10000}, 10, 
  1000000}, {z2}, Delimiter, {{VinR, 2.5}, 0, 
  5}, {VinR}, {{VinC, 2}, -VMax, VMax}, {VinC}]`
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Note that the slider can be more finely controlled, to quote from [Slider](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slider.html): The resulting slider can be finely manipulated by holding down the Alt key (or Option on Macintosh) while dragging the mouse. This causes the slider to move at 1/20 the rate of the mouse. The slider can be even more finely manipulated by also holding the Shift and/or Ctrl keys.

Comment: @Simon this comment is worthy of inclusion in your answer, IMHO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple fix is to just make the slider manipulate the exponent, and plug in e.g. `10^z1` where you need the actual value:

```
Manipulate[10^z1, {{z1, 5}, 2, 6}] (* 100 to 1M *)
```

In your particular case, you could of course also input a list of standard resistor values to pick from:

```
Manipulate[z1, {z1, {100, 110, 120, 130, 150, 160, 180, 200, 220, 240, 270}}]
```

HTH!

Comment: +1  Yes, sliding the exponent seems to be the way to go. This  approach is generally useful for zooming in or out by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: nvm, figured it out: Item[Dynamic[10^Z1]]

Answer (score 7):

Michael's answer is probably the best, i.e. just get the user to specify the exponent. An alternate solution is to make a `LogSlider` type command. Here's a simple example:

```
LogSlider[{v:Dynamic[var_], v0_?Positive}, {min_?Positive, max_?Positive}, 
   base_:10, options___] := DynamicModule[{ev}, Dynamic[
                              var = base^ev; 
                              Slider[Dynamic[ev], Log[base, {min, max}]]]]
LogSlider[v:Dynamic[var_], {min_?Positive, max_?Positive}, 
   base_:10, options___] :=  LogSlider[{v, min}, {min, max}]
```

The function only has a subset of the flexibility of `Slider` and will have to be extended if you want custom step sizes etc...

You then modify your `Manipulate` by specifying the variables using 
`{{z1, 10000}, 10, 1000000, LogSlider[##]&}` etc...

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But there's a problem. Here's what I found out after I test your code: Whether initial value is specified for Manipulate argument z1, "LogSlider" would receive arguments in this format "Dynamic[z1], {min, max}". So the first form of "LogSlider" listed above is unnecessary and "v0" never gets assigned. In order to have the log slider take into account the initial value is to add "ev = Log[base, var];" in DynamicModule just before the "Dynamic" object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final result:
`Manipulate[
 Evaluate[Round[10^Z2]/(Round[10^Z1] + Round[10^Z2])*Vin] "V",
 {{Z1, 5}, 2, 6},
 Pane["Z1  = " Dynamic[Round[10^Z1] "[CapitalOmega]"], 
  ImageMargins -> {{2.5, 0}, {3, 0}}],
 {{Z2, 5}, 2, 6},
 Pane["Z2  = " Dynamic[Round[10^Z2] "[CapitalOmega]"], 
  ImageMargins -> {{2.5, 0}, {0, -5}}], {{Vin, 2.5}, 0, VMax}, 
 Pane["Vin  = " Dynamic[Vin "V"], ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, -5}}]]`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start to LogSlider that produces the standard two-way behavior the other controls have.

```
LogSlider[Dynamic[x_], max_] := 
 Module[{exp}, 
  Dynamic[exp = Log[max, x]; 
   Slider[Dynamic[exp, (exp = #; x = max^exp) &]]]]

{LogSlider[Dynamic@x, 10^6], Dynamic@x}
```